# html javascript text will not replace

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to find and replace the text in my textbox.

this is my script

```
<script>

function findnReplace() {
           
        var str = document.getElementById("source").value;
        var find = document.getElementById("find").value;
        var replace = document.getElementById("replace").value;
        var resultString = str.replace(find, replace);
        var numreplace = new RegExp(find, 'g');

        document.getElementById("source").innerHTML = resultString;

        //find the number of words found and replaced
            var num = str.match(numreplace).length;

            if (num == 0) {
              var no = "No words are replaced.";
              document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = no;
            } else {
              var n = num + " word(s) replaced.";
              document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = n;
            }
      }
</script>
```

and here is my html code

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<textarea name="text" id="source" rows="3"  cols="20" required>Hello Testing
                </textarea><br><br>
<tr>
                        <td>Find:</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="find" name="find" onkeyup="replaceNum()" size="30">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>Replace:</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="replace" name="replace" onkeyup="replaceNum()" size="30">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
    
                </table>    
                
                <input id="findnReplaceButton" type="button" value="Find & Replace" 
                onclick="findnReplace()" title="Fill in both textbox"/>

                <span id="num"></span>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

expected result:

[image]

however, this is what i am getting:

[image]

ALTHOUGH it says "3words replaced" but the text in the textbox didnt get replaced.

Comment: textarea's have value, not innerHTML

Comment: @epascarello oh!! i got it! thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

On your script, you have run `str.replace` function without regex. So it will replace the first match only.

You have defined `numreplace` regex but have not used it.

So to make it work, it is needed to place `str.replace` after `numreplace` variable definition and use that regex inside `str.replace` function as follows.

```js
function findnReplace() {
  var str = document.getElementById("source").value;
  var find = document.getElementById("find").value;
  var replace = document.getElementById("replace").value;
  var numreplace = new RegExp(find, 'g');
  var resultString = str.replace(numreplace, replace);

  document.getElementById("source").innerHTML = resultString;

  //find the number of words found and replaced
  var num = str.match(numreplace).length;

  if (num == 0) {
    var no = "No words are replaced.";
    document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = no;
  } else {
    var n = num + " word(s) replaced.";
    document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = n;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <textarea name="text" id="source" rows="3" cols="20" required>Hi Hi Hi Hi Testing</textarea><br><br>
  <tr>
    <td>Find:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="find" name="find" size="30">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Replace:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="replace" name="replace" size="30">
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>

<input id="findnReplaceButton" type="button" value="Find & Replace" onclick="findnReplace()"
  title="Fill in both textbox" />

<span id="num"></span>
</table>
```